# How to install tuxcut?

Tags: software-installation

need tuxcut to see who is on my network.. I used netcut on windows , and recently found out that tuxcut is the linux alternative of netcut.

Thnx in advance :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download the tuxcut deb file from this [Sourceforge link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/helal/repository/pool/main/t/tuxcut/tuxcut_5.0_all.deb?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fhelal%2Ffiles%2Frepository%2Fpool%2Fmain%2Ft%2Ftuxcut%2F&ts=1473227246&use_mirror=vorboss)
2. Install it's dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wondershaper python-qt4 arp-scan dsniff arptables
   ```
3. Install the tuxcut's deb file with dpkg

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i tuxcut_5.0_all.deb
   ```

Comment: Thnx for this quick reply! I will check it if it works and let you know :D

Comment: I did what u asked and after that typed tuxcut on terminal and hit enter... but it is not in english... maybe arabic.. what to do?

Comment: @AmitSenGupta you need to change the language. Let me update the answer

Comment: sorry i changed the language now. but whenever i select protection mode it is showing in the terminal that "This is not a RedHat based distro"

Comment: @AmitSenGupta I can't help on this one. That one might be a RedHat only feature

Comment: I tried that and it said dpkg: error processing archive tuxcut_5.0_all.deb (--install): cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing: tuxcut_5.0_all.deb

Comment: @Zondollor make sure you're on the directory where the .deb file is downloaded. If it's in _Downloads_ dir, you need to use `cd` command to go there.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for Ubuntu 19.04 onward. 
For latest version of Tuxcut (Currently 6.1), use this link [Tuxcut latest version](https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut/releases)

Download the .deb file of the latest version and install on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score -2):

Download the tuxcut deb file the above same link
, install it's dependencie

```
sudo apt-get install wondershaper python-qt4 arp-scan dsniff arptables
```

Create the following file

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut
```

Install the tuxcut's deb file with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i tuxcut_5.0_all.deb
```

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/run-tuxcut` do? Why is it necessary?

Comment: tuxcut_5.0_all.deb is looking for run-tuxcut file in /usr/bin/

Comment: This should either be a comment on or an edit to the other answer, which apparently didn't need this change for it to be accepted as a working answer.