# Tuxcut does not run on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 after long time of using edition 16.04. I used to use Tuxcut, but when I installed it on 18.04 that's what I get. Please help.

[image]

Comment: How did you installed tuxcut? Please add output of `which tuxcut` to the question. When was it installed - in 16.04 LTS (before upgrade) or in 18.04 LTS?

Comment: i  upgraded from 16.04 to 181.04 i thought i might solve some problems like the late in opening the os. it might takes 15m to load  so i removed it and re installed it .

Comment: i installed tux cut with those commands
1-sudo apt-get install wondershaper python-qt4 arp-scan dsniff arptables
2-sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut
3-sudo dpkg -i tuxcut_5.0_all.deb

Comment: i found those commands here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/821968/how-to-install-tuxcut

Comment: I think you are running Ubuntu using Wayland. Try to logout and login to the *Ubuntu on Xorg* session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to download newer version from official [GitHub repository](http://a-atalla.github.io/tuxcut/):

```
wget https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut/releases/download/6.1/tuxcut_6.1_amd64.deb
sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut # to fix 5.0 removal script
sudo apt-get install ./tuxcut_6.1_amd64.deb
```

Then start its service with

```
sudo systemctl start tuxcutd.service
```

and launch the application with `tuxcut` (on Wayland or on Xorg - does not matter):

[image: TuxCut 6.1]

---

Note: on my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell and Wayland I can't launch version 5.0 of `tuxcut` (I get the "`Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyrun.py: cannot connect to X server :0`" error).

To run the application you should logout from the session and select *Ubuntu* session on the login screen.

[image: selecting Ubuntu session]

Then it should work with `tuxcut` command:

[image: TuxCut on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Xorg]

but I can't understand its output :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your support .
I tried with tuxcut5 but it gives me the frame of the app without the content Iam 
installing tuxcut6 now :)

Comment: Hey , thanks for your help . I couldn't work with version 5 of Tuxcut ,So I installed version 6 due to your advice but strange matter happened , when i run Tuxcut ,it dosn't run responding with(command not fount ) :) but it starts with click on the icon "it's first time to run from Gui " if you have any explanation it will be honer. THANKs  again

Comment: I did not see this message. I ran this program first time to help you. So you can [accept my answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped.